# Parent element with only child has height even if the only child had all paddings, margins, height and width set to zero

Tags: html, css

I encountered a problem: Parent element with only child has height even if the only child had all paddings, margins, borders, outline, height and width set to zero, however when I set display to none it suddenly works.

Why is this happening? What have I forgotten? How can I reach the point when parrent element will have height of zero without altering the height of parent element?

Here is quick snippet I've made.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

div{
  border: 3px red solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text"></div>
```

Thanks.

Edit:
I need input to be displayed as inline-block as well, is there any way to do that with display inline-block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are facing the behavior of `inline-block` elements and their alignment. So to fix this you need to set `line-height:0` to the div like suggested by [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269990/8620333) or `font-size:0` AND change the alignment of the input as by default it's baseline.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

div{
  border: 3px red solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0;
  /*Or
  line-height:0;*/
}

input{
  /*display: inline-block; no needed since it's the default value */
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  vertical-align:top; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! It worked when I replaced ``line-height: 0;`` to ``font-size: 0;``. ``vertical-align: top;`` is not required. I am marking this answer as solution.

Answer (score 4):

Set the divs `line-height` to `0`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 3px red solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: If you look closely, or use dev tools, you can see that div is still 6.5px heigh - is there any way to animate this away?

Answer (score 2):

Set the input to `display: block`

Comment: I've edited the question: I need to display that input as inline-block.